# is it true that swift optional values only needs to be unwrapped once and then it can be used multiple times without unwrapping it again?

Tags: swift, option-type, unwrap

I'm new to Swift and is trying out the beginner's project of building a calculator. I understand that "display.text" returns an optional string and the string value inside of it has to be unwrapped with "!" before it can be used.

However, I have noticed "display.text" only needs to be unwrapped once and then it can be used multiple times without unwrapping it again. Is this true for Swift optional values? Where could I find some guidelines regarding to the matter?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

    var userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = false

    @IBAction func appendDigit(sender: UIButton) {
        let digit = sender.currentTitle!
        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber {
            display.text = display.text! + digit
        } else {
            display.text = digit
            userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: `the string value inside of it has to be unwrapped with "!" ` No, bad start. :) Use safe unwrapping instead, with "if let" for example. Read the [Swift documentation about Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330), it's a very important concept.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice, will take it on board :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should generally avoid to forcibly unwrap optionals (with operator `!`), as this will yield a runtime exception in case the optional contains `nil`. Below follows some techniques to handle unwrapping of optionals.

**Optional binding**

Note that the only way you can *"unwrap it once and then use it multiple times"* if if you *unwrap and **assign** it to another non-optional variable to the same inherent type*.

This is what is done when using [**optional binding**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html):

```
/* Example setup */
let display: UILabel = UILabel()
let digit = "1"

/* optional binding using if-let:
   _assign_ unwrapped value (if non-nil) to 'unwrapped' */
if let unwrappedText = display.text {
    // 'unwrapped' resides in scope inside of the if-let block
    display.text = unwrappedText + digit
}
else {
    display.text = digit
}

/* optional binding using guard-let-else:
   _assign_ unwrapped value (if non-nil) to 'unwrapped' */
func foo(disp: UILabel, _ dig: String) {
    guard let unwrappedText = display.text else {
        display.text = digit
        return
    }
    // 'unwrapped' resides in scope outside of the guard-let-else block
    display.text = unwrappedText + digit
}
foo(display, digit)
```

**Nil coalescing operator**

If you don't want to explicitly assign the unwrapped value using conditional binding, you can make use of the [**nil coalescing operator**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html) for safe unwrapping.

```
/* nil coalescing operator */
display.text = (display.text ?? "") + digit
```

Now, you could, however, use the nil coalescing operator in a semi-optional-binding fashion; assign the unwrapped value of an optional or some default value if the optional is nil:

```
let metaUnwrapped = display.text ?? ""
```

Immutable `metaUnwrapped` would be available in its scope, and contain the value of `display.text` (at assignment), if non-`nil`, or the default value `""`, if `display.text` was `nil` at assignment. You could use `metaUnwrapped` in the same fashion as immutable `unwrapped` in the optional binding examples above:

```
display.text = metaUnwrapped + digit
```

**Optional chaining**

This is slightly off-base w.r.t. your question, but since we're on the subject of optionals and unwrapping, I might as well mention [**optional chaining**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html).

Optional chaining can be used to access properties of some optional property, given that the optional property is not `nil`. As an example, say you want to count the number of characters in the `display.text`, but naturally only if the optional `.text` property is non-`nil`. In this case, optional chaining combined with the nil coalescing operator could be a proper method of choice:

```
let numCharacters = display.text?.characters.count ?? 0
    /* if text != nil, returns character count; otherwise, by
       nil coalescing operator, returns 0 /*
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation!! It is way beyond my expectation! Thanks again for your help! god bless you

Comment: @dzjustinli3 Happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

Two standard options for unwrapping an optional where it can be used again:

1) if let

```
if let unwrappedValue = someOptional {
  // unwrappedValue can be used only inside this block of code
}
```

2) guard

```
guard let unwrappedValue = someOptional else { return } 
/// unwrappedValue can be used as long as it is in scope
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
guard let displayText = display.text else {
    // handle the case when optional has nil value
}

// In this scope you can use non-nil value of display.text as displayText.
print("displayText = \(displayText)")
```

This is how you can use optional values after unwrapping once. Another simpler way would be to just use instead of `guard-let`.

```
if let displayText = display.text else {
    // safely unwrapped
}
```

Hope that helped!

Check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) for more help.